# In a wpf project I am importing excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Do I need Office Primary Interop Assemblies to deploy?

Tags: excel, wpf

I am new to WPF and trying to read an excel template using C# model class in my application.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you've tried and what makes you think you need it or not?

Answer (score 0):

You not only need to deploy the interop assembly that you reference along with your application, you would also need to install Excel on the client machines.

Instead of relying on interop, you'd better use some open-source library such as for example [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) to handle Excel files in your application.

This should work fine as long as you restrict the use to import files of the open-sourced .xlsx format instead of the proprietary old .xsl format.